R: how to display # of unique values for each name in list
I'm attempting to loop through a list like this:
mylist <- list( # not meant to be correct or exact
    countries = c('USA', 'Canada'),
    area = c('big', 'bigger'),
    symbol = c('Eagle', 'leaf'),
    n   = c('1','2','3','1')
)

and print the number of unique values in each
print(unique(mylist$countries))
for (col_name in names(mylist)) {
    print(paste(col_name, mylist$col_name))
    n_unique = unique(mylist$col_name) # col_name is apparently invalid
    print(n_unique)
}

but it appears that the problem is that I cannot refer to the iteration variable inside the for loop.
How can I alter the for loop so that I can print the number of unique values for each name?

You can use lapply(mylist, unique).  If you want to stick with your loop, use mylist[[col_name]] and not mylist$col_name.

Adding to Iroha, if you want to print the "number of uniques" instead of the uniques themselves: lapply(lapply(mylist, unique), length)
